# How to put in mathematica what I want: setting error?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, settings

I downloaded mathematica 9 a while ago, and when I put I try to try something like 'f[x]={{1,2}}', My screen instead reads 'f8x8 = ;;1,2??'. While typing it also switches notation as if it is displaying the wrong way.

I keep getting the following error as well: 'The stretchable character 0x5b in the Mathematica2Mono font (size 13) has a repeating piece (0x81) that is zero size.'

Does anyone know what this means or how to remedy the situation? I'm new to mathematica and am struggling to get to anything remotely familiar. I have uninstalled and reinstalled as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about software installation and should be referred to customer support

Answer (score 0):

Contact Wolfram support. They provide whatever it takes to get it installed and running.

http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/